# TapAndPay is not initializing and showing only 15002 error code

Tags: android, google-pay

I have an app where GooglePay is enabled. Before I show to people the GooglePay button, I am initializing this `TapAndPayClient` like this:

```
private val tapAndPayClient: TapAndPayClient by lazy {
    TapAndPay.getClient(requireContext())
}

// ...

val task = tapAndPayClient.isTokenized(
           IsTokenizedRequest.Builder()
           .setIdentifier("identifier") // shouldn't it be some real thing?
           .setNetwork(TapAndPay.CARD_NETWORK_MASTERCARD)
           .setTokenServiceProvider(TapAndPay.TOKEN_PROVIDER_MASTERCARD)
           .build())
    
task.addOnFailureListener { ex ->
    println("hop: this is an error message=$ex.message") // showing 15002
}
```

It is always triggering the `OnFailureListener` callback. The exception is `ApiException` with `15002` message.

I looked through the internet and couldn't find what this `15002` mean.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

`identifier` is the final 4 digits of the card you're asking tapAndPay SDK